# buildout seems don't correctly execute setup.py

Tags: python, buildout

buildout.cfg

```
[buildout]
parts = icom
develop = .
unzip = true
include-site-packages = false
eggs = 
       sqlalchemy
       flask
       scss

[icom]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${buildout:eggs}
interpreter = python
scripts = 
          create_db
          scss
```

**there is a `create_db` in scripts.**

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name = "icom",
    version = "1.0",
    url = 'http://domain.com',
    license = 'BSD',
    description = "",
    author = 'lzyy',
    author_email = 'someone@some.com',
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'': 'src'},
    install_requires = ['setuptools', 'flask', 'sqlalchemy', 'scss', 'flask-actions'],
    zip_safe = False,
    entry_points = '''
    [console_scripts]
    create_db = models.tables:create_db
    ''',
)
```

**note `flask-actions` is not in buildout.cfg**

when i run `bin/buildout -vv` got these messages

```
Installing 'zc.buildout', 'setuptools'.
We have the best distribution that satisfies 'zc.buildout'.
Picked: zc.buildout = 1.5.2
We have a develop egg: setuptools 0.6c12dev-r85381
Develop: '/Users/healdream/Dropbox/project/icom/.'
in: '/Users/healdream/Dropbox/project/icom/.'
/var/folders/70/d_0n450n7_17fj_httj_sbf00000gn/T/tmpfWBBK3 develop -mxN -d /Users/healdream/Dropbox/project/icom/develop-eggs/tmpfcXY_fbuild
running develop
running egg_info
writing requirements to src/icom.egg-info/requires.txt
writing src/icom.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/icom.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/icom.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to src/icom.egg-info/entry_points.txt
reading manifest file 'src/icom.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src/icom.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /Users/healdream/Dropbox/project/icom/develop-eggs/tmpfcXY_fbuild/icom.egg-link (link to src)

Installed /Users/healdream/Dropbox/project/icom/src
```

but there is no `create_db.py` under bin dir, and didn't install flask-actions either

Comment: a bit shame, i didn't add current project in buildout.cfg's [buildout] section's eggs.

Comment: So, your question is now answered? You are correct, you are missing `icom` in your eggs list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include `icom` in your eggs list. Either add it to the `[buildout]` section:

```
[buildout]
...
eggs =
   icom
   sqlalchemy
   flask
   scss
```

or to the `[icom]` section:

```
[icom]
recipe = zc.recipe.egg
eggs =
    icom
    ${buildout:eggs}
...
```